# windows file system / explorer ssh plugin

Tags: windows, filesystems, plugins

Does anyone know of a Windows explore/filesystem plugin that maps to remote system via SSH?

There was a tool called GmailFS that exposed Gmail account as file system that appeared in explorer so that users could directly store files in that account. I am looking for something similar for SSH. I want to access Linux's files directly in explorer via this plugin. I know Samba is one way but I want to know if same can be achieved via SSH.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map SSH drive in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/291786/map-ssh-drive-in-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search for "windows sshfs" turned up [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) and [ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/windows).

I have never tried Dokan, but it appears to be a one-man open source project.

ExpanDrive is a commercial product, going for $39.95 at this writing. I installed the 30-day free trial, and it has worked really well. I mounted one of my servers over SSH and it looks and acts like any other network drive.